# jQuery UI Sortable with position absolute list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I wnated to use UI Sortable for absolute positioning in my application. Please help me.

I have certain list element with their own position like:

```
<div class="sort">
    <div class="list" style="top:0px; height:30px;">List 01</div>
    <div class="list" style="top:35px; height:50px;">List 02</div>
    <div class="list" style="top:90px; height:80px;">List 03</div>
    <div class="list" style="top:175px; height:60px;">List 04</div>
    <div class="list" style="top:240px; height:30px;">List 05</div>
</div>
```

It has own position from top to bottom. I need it should be sortable.

```
$(function(){
    $('.sort').sortable();
});
```

Once we sorting the top position should be updated in element style.

check the fiddle please : http://jsfiddle.net/Vipin/tw2dnqdb/25/

Comment: is absolute positioning a requirement ?

Comment: Yes Gourav. It is mandatory for application

Comment: After looking into the code of the jQuery UI .sortable() function, it looks like it just wasn't designed to handle this situation. So I'll ask a question and then offer one alternative. First, why are absolute positions mandatory for this application? Is it not possible to just use a list and give each element a bottom-margin of 5 px? Second, the only other option I can see is to implement a sortable function yourself using .draggable() and .droppable() but it is going to be A BEAR.